# How to delete a div including a unique ID generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, uniqueidentifier, queryselector

I'm fairly new to JS, sorry if I'm not clear enough.

I'm creating a to do list. I've generated a div for every new task added. Each of those div contain two classes.

1. a generic one
2. a unique ID using new Date().getTime();

Now I need to allow to delete specific tasks. But it seems like I'm not able to delete a div using the unique ID. It's maybe because I'm not getting the data back? How to fix that?

```js
const myArray = [];

function myPushFunction(x){ // 3rd
    let itemToPush = myArray.push(x);
    return itemToPush;
}

function getMyInputValue(){
    let myInputValue = document.querySelector("#myInput").value;
    document.querySelector("#TasksList").innerHTML + myInputValue; 
    myPushFunction(myInputValue); 

    let taskScope = document.querySelector("#TasksList");

    let div1 = document.createElement("div");
    taskScope.appendChild(div1);


    let addItem = document.createTextNode(myInputValue);
    div1.appendChild(addItem);

    let idClass = "p" + new Date().getTime();
    div1.classList.add("taskdesign", idClass);

    let buttonDelete = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    div1.appendChild(buttonDelete);

    buttonDelete.classList.add("buttondeletedesign");

    let span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    span.innerHTML = "delete";
    buttonDelete.appendChild(span);

    span.classList.add("material-icons-outlined");

    buttonDelete.onclick = function(event) {
    const deleteElement = document.querySelector(`.${idClass}`);
        deleteElement.remove();
    }



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="todo-design.css">
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Toudou</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myfullpage">
<h1>Toudou</h1>
    <div id="NewTask">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Task to add">
    <button id="button" onclick="getMyInputValue()">Add</button>
    </div>

    <div id="TasksList"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="testjs-1.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanksss

Comment: It's easy to get a reference to the button that was clicked inside the onclick function.  From there you can find which task div it's in, and remove it.  Show your HTML for help with this.  You don't need to assign unique ids.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just added my HTML. But I need a unique ID each time a task div is created in order to find the specific div to delete dynamically. But when I use the querySelector to target my dynamically generated ID (var), and use the remove function this message appears in my console "Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '1648732007395' is not a valid selector.".

Comment: `id` should not start with a `number`. Aside of that, you really don't need the id for what you want to do; instead you need simple DOM traversal to solve the problem. Please correct your snippet so it shows you best attempt. Currently it's a mixed thing that cannot be run.

Comment: `But I need a unique ID each time a task div is created in order to find the specific div to delete dynamically` - no.  You know which button was clicked.  You know what it's parent node is (the div you want to delete).  You can delete it without IDs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, it worked perfectly using the parent node! @connexo I updated the snippet

Answer (score 0):

### Unique IDs

The first thing you need are unique IDs for a task in the ToDo list. Time is not a very good candidate as if you create tasks programmatically it's possible two timestamps get the same ID. See the following sample script that shows that the instructions are executed so fast that they have the same timestamp.

```js
const timestamp = new Date()
const timestamp2 = new Date()

console.log(timestamp.getTime())
console.log(timestamp2.getTime())
```

As JavaScript is [single threaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) we could use a simple counter instead. Another possibility would be [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

In my implementation provided below I have used a simple counter. See private class attribute `#curId` of class `ToDoList` for this.

### Tasks

You should keep tasks in a data structure e.g. a simple array to have all the task information ready in a structured form for your program to work with. This is your state. Using that, it is way easier to manage your application than just putting this information in classes, IDs and so on within the HTML as you seem to do it.

In my implementation provided below I have used a simple array to hold the tasks. See private class attribute `#tasks` in `ToDoList`. A task in my implementation is just an instance of the my `Task` class, consequently `#tasks` is an array of `Task` instances that are manages by an instance of the `ToDoList` class.

### How to delete?

Deletion can be done when you attach a delete button to every task and to that delete button you attach an event handler. Whenever that button is clicked, the event handler will be triggered and should execute the following steps:

- delete the task from your task array (= state)
- delete the task from the view (= HMTL page)

To identify the task we use its unique ID and we will provide that ID as a parameter to the `onclick` handler of the delete button. I do this when we create the delete button cause at this time we know which task this button is going to delete.

Please see methods `#addTaskToView()` and `#createDeleteButton()` button methods of class `ToDoList` in my implementation provided below to see how I have done this.

### Implementation: ToDo-List

My implementation of a very simple ToDo-List which can only delete tasks  (using the UI) from a predefined list of task, but can easily be extended it to be able to add task and much more than that.

My implementation is object-oriented as this is works quite well for the given task and even allows to treat a ToDo-list as one independent component in your application similar to how frontend frameworks like React would do it. My snippet shows how this can be useful to effortless create two ToDoList with two simple commands `new ToDoList()`.

You may want to read on some of the feature I have used in the MDN docs with the most important being:

- [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)
- [Private class features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)
- [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/)

```js
/**
 * For demo purposes assume a user already had created these tasks
 */
const tasks = [
  {
    title: "My task 1",
    desc: "Desc for my task",
  },
  {
    title: "My task 2",
    desc: "Desc for my task 2",
  },
  {
    title: "My task dfssdf",
    desc: "Desc for my task fsddsfsd",
  },
  {
    title: "My task 1",
    desc: "Desc for my task",
  },
  {
    title: "My task 2",
    desc: "Desc for my task 2",
  },
  {
    title: "My task dfssdf",
    desc: "Desc for my task fsddsfsd",
  },
];

class Task {
  /**
   * @private
   * @type {number}
   */
  #id;
  /**
   * @private
   * @type {string}
   */
  #title;
  /**
   * @private
   * @type {string}
   */
  #description;

  constructor(id, title, description) {
    this.#id = id;
    this.#title = title;
    this.#description = description;
  }

  /**
   * Create a copy of an existing task.
   * @param {Task} task task to create a copy from
   * @returns deep copy of given task
   */
  static #from(task) {
    return new Task(task);
  }

  /**
   * Copy the task.
   * @returns 1:1 deep-copy of the task
   */
  clone() {
    return Task.#from(this);
  }

  get id() {
    return this.#id;
  }

  get title() {
    return this.#title;
  }

  get description() {
    return this.#description;
  }
}

class ToDoList {
  /**
   * List of tasks in this ToDo list.
   * @private
   * @type {Array<Task>}
   */
  #tasks;
  /**
   * Current ID. Counter used to assign a unique ID to a task within the list
   * @private
   * @type {number}
   */
  #curId;
  /**
   * <ul> tag that contains all list items
   * @private
   * @type {HTMLUListElement}
   */
  #list;
  /**
   * Root HTML element this list is attached to.
   * @private
   * @type {HTMLElement}
   */
  #root;

  /**
   * Create a new ToDo list.
   * @param {HTMLElement} attachTo root element this ToDo list is attached to
   * @param {string} title title for the ToDo list
   */
  constructor(attachTo, title) {
    this.#tasks = [];
    this.#curId = 1;
    if (!attachTo instanceof HTMLElement) throw "No valid wrapper element given!";
    this.#root = attachTo;
    this.#list = this.#createList()
    this.#addToDoListToView(title)
  }

  /**
   * Initialize the ToDo list 
   * @param {string} title title for todo list
   */
  #addToDoListToView(title){
    const header = this.#createToDoListHeader(title);
    this.#root.append(header, this.#list);
  }

  #createList(){
    return document.createElement("ul");
  }

  #createToDoListHeader(title){
    const heading = document.createElement("h1");
    heading.textContent = title;
    return heading;
  }

  get tasks() {
    // SoC: return copy; don't let callers manipulate the state of the actual task array
    return this.#tasks.slice();
  }

  get curId() {
    return this.#curId;
  }

  get wrapper() {
    return this.#list;
  }

  /**
   * Add a newly created task to the view.
   * @param {Task} newTask new task
   */
  #addTaskToView(newTask) {
    // new list item as a parent
    const listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.classList.add("task");
    // a heading for the title
    const heading = document.createElement("h3");
    // create blockquote to show ID of a task
    const taskId = document.createElement("span");
    taskId.classList.add("id");
    // a paragraph for the description
    const desc = document.createElement("p");
    // create the delete button
    const deleteBtn = this.#createDeleteButton(newTask, listItem);

    // set text values for created elements
    heading.textContent = newTask.title;
    desc.textContent = newTask.description;
    taskId.textContent = `Task-ID: ${newTask.id}`;

    // build structure
    listItem.append(taskId, heading, desc, deleteBtn);
    // append to actual TODO list
    this.#list.appendChild(listItem);
  }

  /**
   * Create the delete button for a task.
   * @param {Task} newTask new task
   */
  #createDeleteButton(newTask, listItem) {
    // create a Button to delete the task
    const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
    deleteBtn.textContent = "Delete";
    // here is the important part! Pass the task ID to the delete function that will be called whenever the button is clicked
    deleteBtn.onclick = () => {
      const success = this.deleteTaskById(newTask.id);
      if (!success) {
        alert(
          `Task "ID: ${newTask.id} | ${newTask.title} does not exits and therefore could not be deleted!`
        );
        return;
      }
      this.#deleteTaskFromView(listItem);
    };
    return deleteBtn;
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param {string} title title for the task
   * @param {string} description description for the task
   * @returns newly created task
   */
  addTask(title, description) {
    // better to use an ID that is unique (one could also use UUIDs but for simplicity just count the IDs up)
    const newTask = new Task(this.#curId++, title, description);
    this.#tasks.push(newTask);
    // now add the task to the HTML document
    this.#addTaskToView(newTask);
    // return a copy of the newly created task, SoC: don't allow callers to manipulate internal objects
    return newTask.clone();
  }

  /**
   * Delete a task given its ID.
   * @param {number} id unique ID for a task
   * @returns true if task with given ID was found and deleted, false otherwise
   */
  deleteTaskById(id) {
    const foundIdx = this.#tasks.findIndex((task) => task.id === id);
    if (foundIdx !== -1) {
      this.#tasks.splice(foundIdx, 1)[0];
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Delete a task from the HTML document using it's ID
   * @param {HTMLUListElement} listItem list element containing this task
   */
  #deleteTaskFromView(listItem) {
    listItem.parentNode.removeChild(listItem);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  // container which holds the TODO list
  const container = document.getElementById("container1");
  const container2 = document.getElementById("container2");

  // create the todo list and specify the HTML element it should be attached to
  const todoList = new ToDoList(container, "My ToDo List");
  const todoList2 = new ToDoList(container, "2nd ToDo List");

  // add task list with some predefined tasks
  tasks.forEach((task) => {
    todoList.addTask(task.title, task.desc)
    todoList2.addTask(task.title, task.desc)
  });
});
```

```css
.task{
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.id {
  font-size: small;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

Comment: `console.log(timestamp.getTime()); console.log(timestamp.getTime());` <-- I think the second one is meant to be `timestamp2`. +10000000 for the time, efforts. Wish I could add more than just 1 up-vote. :-)

Comment: Thanks mate. Fixed :) Was actually quite fun to code as I myself pretty much have just more or less skipped vanilla JS to do this kind of thing as it quickly was apparent to me that it is quite tedious and moved on to React :D Doing this let's you appreciate the work React is doing for you again :D

Comment: `id` is not needed here.

Comment: You're right, it is not. But it was explicitly mentioned in the question and it certainly makes handling the tasks easier, especially if you consider expanding on this example to later include a backend and a database to store tasks. Also when you think about moving on to React someday you will need a key property that is unique, so it's certainly a more common use-case in the real-world to have an ID than not to have one.

Comment: @Mushroomator probably better to generate those "expanded example" IDs in the database than via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Example of not using IDs and how to locate the right elements within the click handler.

```js
const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button.deleteBtn");

for (let d of deleteButtons) {
  d.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // e.target is the button that was clicked!
    let theButton = e.target;
    // theButton.parentNode is the div that the button is in!
    let theDiv = theButton.parentNode;
    theDiv.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="myfullpage">
  <h1>Toudou</h1>

  <div id="TasksList">
    <div class="task">
      <span>task1</span>
      <button class='deleteBtn'>Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="task">
      <span>task2</span>
      <button class='deleteBtn'>Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="task">
      <span>task3</span>
      <button class='deleteBtn'>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```